# C# Poker: how to keep track of players and make game engine (classes) preflop, flop, turn, river?

Tags: c#

Im recently studying c# and want to create a 'simple' console app poker game.
Ive created classes: player, hand, deck, dealer. Dealer gets cards out of the deck and assigns it to player instances. What I'm struggling with now is how to progress further? I need to make some gameplay possible.

This is what i have coded thusfar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Deck d = new Deck();
            Player[] players = new Player[2];
            Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

            players[0] = new Player("M");
            players[1] = new Player("T");


        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(player.name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            player.AddCardsToHand(dealer);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("View hand van player 1");
        foreach (string card in players[0].ViewHandCards())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("View hand van player 2");

        foreach (string card in players[1].ViewHandCards())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Number of players instantiated:");
        Console.WriteLine(Player.playerCount);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Number of hands instantiated:");
        Console.WriteLine(Hand.handCount);
        Console.WriteLine();

        dealer.SetMoneyAmount(players[0]);
        dealer.SetMoneyAmount(players[1], 150);

        Console.WriteLine("Money player 1:");
        Console.WriteLine(players[0].MoneyAmount);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Money player 2:");
        Console.WriteLine(players[1].MoneyAmount);
        Console.WriteLine();

        int index = 0;
        dealer.SetDealer(players[index]);

        Console.WriteLine("Dealer: " + dealer.GetDealer());

        // how to know in a class how many players there are and there values?
        // create a class containing the players array?


    }
}
class Settings
{
    // static string dealer;
    public static int dealerIndex;
    public static string dealerName;
    public 
}
class User
{
    public string name;
}
class Player : User
{
    Hand h = new Hand();
    public static int playerCount;


    private double moneyAmount;
    public bool dealerButton;

    public double MoneyAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return moneyAmount;
        }
        set
        {
            moneyAmount = value;
        }
    }

    public int NumOfCardsInHand()
    {

        return h.cardsInHand;
    }
    public string[] ViewHandCards()
    {

        return h.handCards;
    }
    public void AddCardsToHand(Dealer d)
    {
        d.DealCard(h);
        d.DealCard(h);
    }
    public Player(string n)
    {
        this.name = n;
        playerCount++;
    }
}
class Hand
{
    public static int handCount;

    public int cardsInHand = 0;
    public string[] handCards = new string[2];
    public Hand()
    {
        handCount++;
    }

}
class Dealer
{
    Deck d = new Deck();
    //public void StartGame()
    //{

    //}
    public void DealCard(Hand h)
    {
        if (h.cardsInHand < 2)
        {


            if (h.cardsInHand == 0)
                h.handCards[0] = d.NextCard();
            if (h.cardsInHand == 1)
                h.handCards[1] = d.NextCard();
            h.cardsInHand++;

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Meer dan 2 kaarten per hand is niet toegestaan");

        }

    }
    public void SetMoneyAmount(Player p, double amount = 100)
    {
        p.MoneyAmount = amount;
    }
    public void SetDealer(Player p)
    {
        p.dealerButton = true;
        Settings.dealerName = p.name;

    }
    public string GetDealer()
    {
        return Settings.dealerName;
    }

}
class Deck
{
    public int numOfCards = 52;
    public string[] cards = new string[13];
    public string[] playingCards = new string[52];
    public string[] cardsDealt = new string[52];
    Random r = new Random();
    int y = 0;

    public string NextCard()
    {
        string nextCard = "-";

        int x = 0;

        while (x < 1)
        {
            nextCard = playingCards[r.Next(0, playingCards.Length)];

            if (!cardsDealt.Contains(nextCard))
            {
                cardsDealt[y] = nextCard;
                y++;
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reeds gedeelde kaart bijna opnieuw gedeeld!");
                x = 0;
            }

        }
        return nextCard;
    }
    public void ConstructDeck()
    {
        // spade club heart diamond
        this.cards[0] = "A";
        this.cards[1] = "K";
        this.cards[2] = "Q";
        this.cards[3] = "J";
        this.cards[4] = "10";
        this.cards[5] = "9";
        this.cards[6] = "8";
        this.cards[7] = "7";
        this.cards[8] = "6";
        this.cards[9] = "5";
        this.cards[10] = "4";
        this.cards[11] = "3";
        this.cards[12] = "2";

        int x = 0;
        foreach (string card in this.cards)
        {

            this.playingCards[x] = card + "s";
            x++;
            this.playingCards[x] = card + "c";
            x++;
            this.playingCards[x] = card + "h";
            x++;
            this.playingCards[x] = card + "d";
            x++;
        }

    }

    public Deck()
    {
        ConstructDeck();
    }
}
class Bet
{
    public double betAmount;
    public Bet(Player p, double betInput)
    {

        betAmount = betInput;
    }
}
}
```

I have put the player instances in an array and can call them like this players[0] (player 1).

I would like to know if im on the right track here and more specifically how do I keep track of the players I instantiated so that other classes can access the player instance variables? Im assigning one player the dealer status and would need to know where to start asking for other players initiative in the game like needing to bet call check or fold at some given point. I dont know what kind of classes I would need to create for a preflop game, a flop game, a turn game and the river game. Classes for each game name? How would I check if a player finished his action?

I think I should create a class like: preflopgame and identify the dealer than ask initiative (bet fold etc (make classes of betting folding checking etc) of the player thats not the dealer and keep track via a variable that player finished its initiative in the preflopgame class? And if preflopgame is played out: some kind of static boolean field in the class indicating its finished. Than move on to the next game: flopgame. Is this the right way of thinking about this game?

Any suggestions would certainly be much apreciated.
Excuse my English im Dutch from origin.

Comment: A quick comment from a quick review, why is Player inheriting from User? If you're just learning, keep the abstraction to a minimum until the basic concepts make sense.

Comment: Thanks was an example from a book I tested but you are certainly right. In the future I want users to connect to my app and before they become players in a game they are users with some charactaristics.

Comment: "before they become players in a game" means that you *can't* use inheritance. If a `player` *is a* `user`, then when you create a `player` you are duplicating the info of the already-existing `user`. What you really want is for a `user` to be associated with a `player`: perhaps a `player` *has a* `user`. This question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you're struggling with this exercise then I suggest that you solve an easier problem. Can you design a program that lets two people play a trivial card game, like War or Go Fish?